# Where is DatabaseSupport directory in the ArcGIS client?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, oracle-dbms

May I know where is this folder stated in the guide?

DatabaseSupport directory in the ArcGIS client installation location and move it to a location on the Oracle server.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//019v0000000s000000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my **Windows 7** laptop, which has a vanilla install of **ArcGIS for Desktop 10.1 SP1**, the **DatabaseSupport** folder is located in **C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1** - see below.

[image]

Comment: I found it just doing a stupid search but it took me 30mins to search the entire HDD -.-